# Bs4 not scraping all table row elements with findAll

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to do a simple scrape for 'tr' elements from a react-rendered job listing website. It is a relatively large table with ~1000 tr elements, but my code only returns 70 rows.

Is it possible that the website somehow blocks scraping more than 70 rows?

What I've tried:
looping through a bs4 ResultSet from findAll against 'table', 'tr', and 'td' tags. All return 70 rows.

```
table = soup.find('tr', { 'class': 'table-rows' })
for i in table:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: It's possible 70 is the default and more are loaded through JS.

Comment: may be you are making a request using `requests` or `urllib`, try `selenium` instead.

Comment: I am using selenium :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out :)

Simply used selenium methods to grab elements instead bs4. Not sure what the difference is, might be the fact that the website is rendered in JS?

Ex.

```
table = driver.find_element_by_class_name('table-body')
#prints all rows
[print(i.text) for i in table]
```